# Regular Expression Maximum Number Of Characters Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, max, maxlength

So i have this regex:

```
var regex = /^[\S]+(\-[\S]+)$/
```

i want to add one more rule, the rule is that maximum number of characters is 6 or something, how do i do it? my full code looks like this

```
var regex = /^[\S]+(\-[\S]+)$/
var word = "a-a";

if(word.match(regex)){
    console.log("matched");
}else{
    console.log("did not match");
}
console.log(word.length);
```

i've tried `var regex = /^([\S]+(\-[\S]+)){6}$/` but this means they must repeat a-a 6 times, i want the maximum number of characters, something like this:

```
var word = "123-56"
```

to be matched, how do i do it?
and i don't want to use `.length` because i want to implement it into regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead:

```
var regex = /^(?=.{0,6}$)[\S]+\-[\S]+$/
```

Comment: You can even write that as `var regex = /^(?=.{3,6}$)\S+-\S+$/` (the original  regex requires an input string of length 3 and more).